# Sharepoint 2019 users not working unless re-added

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, active-directory-import

I've restored a content database into a Sharepoint Server 2019 web application.  Any user that does not have Full Control is not able to get in and just get a 'Sorry, this list hasn't been shared with you.'

Most users are allowed permission through Domain\Domain Users active directory group. The site works and admins are able to use and browse. I've run the Active Directory Import with default mappings. I'm using claims authentication through windows auth.

If I remove and re-add the user or group then they are able to see the site fine.

Is there a way to update all the users and groups so they're able to access? Does the AD import need to be updated?

I've run

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://sharepoint" -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissions
```

and

```
$WebAppName = "http://sharepoint"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$wa.UseClaimsAuthentication = $true
$wa.Update()

$account = "domain\admin"
$account = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $account -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString()
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$zp = $wa.ZonePolicies("Default")
$p = $zp.Add($account,"PSPolicy")
$fc=$wa.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole("FullControl")
$p.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($fc)
$wa.Update()

$wa.MigrateUsers($true)

$wa.ProvisionGlobally()
```

And both log attempting to convert users but error out with:

```
Configuration error. No migrator configured.    5e01e49e-546b-6002-7dbe-fa0186950239
SPUser '23': Could not get migration data for entity so SKIPPING. Check migrator for further logs
```

For every user and group.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SP did the content DB come from?  If the previous version of SP was not using claims auth you will need to migrate the users to claims.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/migrate-from-classic-mode-to-claims-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: It was not claims before and I've run the powershell commands to convert the site and users to Claims. The site converts and any new users or groups work well but existing users are not converted by the recommended scripts. Each fails in the log file. See the updated post for errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is because of the authentication method used in both farm are different. So when you remove the user and re add, it will added with proper claims or authentication type. That's why user able to access it.

SharePoint 2013: Migrate users from Windows to Claims Authentication：

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Migrate-bbf4ae4d

Similar issue post for your reference:

[SharePoint permissions not working after restore from backup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202792/sharepoint-permissions-not-working-after-restore-from-backup)

Comment: I tried all the Convert or Migrate scripts in that similar posts which looks like the recommended way to do it but I get the errors in the logs describe in the post above I updated. Thoughts ?Thanks for the remove/re-add script. That might be the only way I can do it if the MigrateUsers or Convert-SPWebApplication scripts are failing.